# get_posts does not return multiple post types

Tags: wordpress

I am using **get_posts($query)** to list posts in my WordPress plugin.

If I use it like this:

```
$query['post_type'] = array('post', 'attachment');
```

Then it will not return 'attachment' types, only posts. They will be returned only if I query for them separately, like this:

```
$query['post_type'] = 'attachment';
```

I am using WordPress 4.9.6.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is attachments have post_status == 'inherit' not 'publish' so I would try adding

```
$query['post_status'] = [ 'publish', 'inherit' ];
```

to $args.

Note that this may get more results then intended as post_type == 'post' with post_status == 'inherit' will also be returned. You should probably do two separate queries. This is just an explanation as to why your combined query does not work as expected.

The reason

```
$query['post_type'] = 'attachment';
```

works is the WordPress has the following code in get_posts()

```
if ( empty( $r['post_status'] ) )
    $r['post_status'] = ( 'attachment' == $r['post_type'] ) ? 'inherit' : 'publish';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. It worked using: $query['post_status'] = [ 'publish', 'inherit' ];

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => array('post', 'attachment')
);

$multi_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Make sure to check the name of your custom post type.